# Periodic continuous function

Tags: continuity

Could anyone help me with the following question?

The periodic function $g$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f(x)$ for $0\le x<a$ and $g(x)=g(x+a)$ for all $x$, for some $a>1$. It is given that $g$ is a continuous function. Find the exact value of $a$.

Thanks.

Comment: take $f(x)=x$, then no such $a$ exists. What are the assumptions on $f$?

Comment: there are no assumptions on f

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Assume that $A=\{x>0\mid f(x)=f(0)\}\neq \emptyset$ and suppose that for $a = \min\{x\mid x\in A\}$, $f$ is continuous on $[0,a]$. Show that $a$ is satisfies the required conditions. What happens if $A=\emptyset$? and if $f$ is not continuous on $[0,a]$?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May i know why u made those assumptions? I don't understand the part of f(x)=f(0).

Comment: @user1097856 suppose that $f(a)\neq f(0)$ then what can you say about the continuity of $g$ around $a$ (or $0$ if you prefer)? Remember that $g$ is periodic.

Comment: is it because the period of the function is a, so f(a)=f(0)?